# MailTo Link on facebook wall(phonegap)

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, mailto

hi can anyone please tell me how to post mailto: on facebook wall .I downloaded the facebook SDK from git.But im unable to post mailTo.this is the sdk :https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/

this is the code im using:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'I\'m using the Hackbook web app',
    caption: 'Hackbook for Mobile Web.',
    description: 'Check out Hackbook .',
        link: '<html><body><a href="mailto:vinod.amc@gmail.com"/></body></html>',
    picture: 'http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/img/facebook_icon_large.png',
    actions: [{ name: 'Click Here', link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/mobile-start/' }],
  }, 
  function(response) {
    console.log('publishStory UI response: ', response);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> link: '<html><body><a href="mailto:vinod.amc@gmail.com"/></body></html>'
> ```

That’s not a `link` parameter like Facebook expects it – it expects an HTTP(S) URL.

I know of no way to directly link to email addresses. So your best way to go is to put your email into the message, I’d say.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that from the company’s point of view every time people engage with one another outside of Facebook, this represents a loss of marketable user data. For this reason, Facebook works very hard to discourage communication outside of Facebook, and disabling mailto links in messages and posts is a part of this effort.